# using mediaplayer class to play song present in external sd card but not working

Tags: android

I have already extracted all mp3 files present in SD card and clicking upon a particular song, it calls the class playSong and passes name of a song in its constructor via which I'm trying to play the file using create method of MediaPlayer file, but its not working at all for me as it is showing null pointer exception.

```
public class PlaySong {

    MediaPlayer mp;
    Context context;
    String  title;
    public PlaySong(Context context,String title)
    {
        this.title=title;
        this.context=context;
    }

    public void play_Song()
    {
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Yes", 0).show();
        String [] str=title.split("-");
        String name=str[0];

        //Toast.makeText(context, ""+name, 0).show();
        //mp = new MediaPlayer();
        try
        {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/songs/"+name+".mp3"));
        //mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        //mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, ""+ex, 0).show();

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

NullPointer is only because the Uri.parse did not get the assigned path.
Try printing this path -Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/songs/"+name+".mp3"
My understanding is, It should give you the path with mounted sdcord index,
and the accessible path would be "sdcard/songs/"+name+".mp3"

Comment: it is toasting a file location mnt/sdcard/songs/"+name+".mp3"

Answer (score 0):

Check with this:

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(filelocation));

Also make sure file location is getting correct.

Comment: File location is correct as i have toasted the file location but this code is also not working

Comment: Post your logcat its easy to help

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a very minor mistake of not using trim() function to trim an extra space came in the name of song due to which it was giving null pointer exception.